# Adding class to body tag using jQuery Cycle

Tags: jquery, html, cycle

I want to add a class to the body tag using jQuery.

[Here is my jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/FE9cE/)

JS

```
// Hover Switch
   function fnFadeHover(){$('#feature_fadeSlideshow').cycle($('#feature_fadeBtns li').index($(this).parent()));}
   function fnFadeOut(){}
   $('#feature_fadeSlideshow').cycle({ 
     fx:'fade',
     timeout:6000,
     pause:true,
     before: function(currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag){

       var slide_index = $('#feature_fadeSlideshow .panel').index(nextSlideElement);
       $('body').removeClass('slide').eq(slide_index).addClass('slide');
       $('#feature_fadeBtns li').removeClass('activePager').eq(slide_index).addClass('activePager');



     }});
   $('#feature_fadeBtns li a').hoverIntent(fnFadeHover,300,fnFadeOut);
```

[I am using the jQuery Cycle plugin..](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

What I want to do is add a class to the body tag when I hover over `#feature_fadeBtns li a`. Right now it only adds a class of `activePager` to `#feature_fadeBtns li` I want it to add classes of `firstSlide`, `secondSlide`, `thirdSlide`.

Here is what I started

`$('body').removeClass('slide').eq(slide_index).addClass('slide');`

**What am I doing wrong?
     ​**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you, but this will work:

```
$('body').removeClass('slide').addClass('slide');
```

You don't need the `.eq()` function on the `body` element.

Also, why would you remove class slide and then re-add it? This should be enough:

```
$('body').addClass('slide');
```

Read about the `.eq()` function [here](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) - it's a filter function used to match an element at a specified index.